# Controller under unit test return empty contentAsString

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controllers

have some controller with:

```
  def index() {
    ...
    render(view: 'index', model: [exceptions: exceptions]                                                                                         
    }
```

Also have unit test:

```
  def testIndex(){
    ...
    controller.index()
    assert controller.response.status == 200
    assert controller.response.contentAsString != ""
  }
```

Second assertion fails, as `contentAsString` return "". When I replace my `render()` with `render("html")` - `contentAsString` is fulfilled even under test. What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

index.gsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.exception.ExceptionUtils" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exceptions catched during crawling</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
     $(".stacktrace").hide()
     $("a").click(function(){
       $(this).parents("li").siblings("pre").toggle()
   return false;
     })
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<g:each var="entry" in="${exceptions.entrySet()}">
  Catched <b>${entry.key.name}</b> for these URLs:                                                                                                                                                                                         
  <ol>
    <g:each var="ex" in="${entry.value.entrySet()}">
      <li><a href="${ex.key}">${ex.key}</a>: ${ex.value.message}</li>
        <pre class="stacktrace">
          ${ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex.value)}
        </pre>
</g:each>
  </ol>
</g:each>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Upgrade from grails 2.2.3 to grails 2.2.4 does not help ;(

Comment: Normally I do `response.text`, can you try it?

Comment: Tried. `response.text` also does not work.

Comment: What do you have in your index.gsp?

Comment: index.gsp listed. I works well under `run-app`. Does not work only under `test-app unit:`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I revisited the [Unit Testing](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#9.1%20Unit%20Testing) section of docs. It seems that the `response.contentAsString` can be used only when you render your text directly. For rendering a view, you can check the item "Testing View Rendering" of the docs.

Example:

```
// Test class
class SimpleController {
    def home() {
        render view: "homePage", model: [title: "Hello World"]
    }
    …
}

void testIndex() {
    controller.home()
    assert view == "/simple/homePage"
    assert model.title == "Hello World"
}
```

Comment: how to access rendered HTML content?

Comment: @archer In this case, there's no html content generated. See [Jeff's response](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spock-How-to-render-a-view-inside-a-unit-test-tp4639793p4639798.html) in the mail list.

Comment: If you really need to test the html then you will need to get this `ModelAndView` and do something like [this post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/grails-goodness-render-gsp-views-and.html) does.

Comment: yeah, thank you. But inside Unit Test it's not initialized. Will try to move to integration and see

Comment: Does not work for me even in production. For some reason model data is not available from inside gsp. Probably it can't be used from the controllers and default render method should be used there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't followed what you've done. Can you update your question with the new code?